# Upon defining a new constant update the names of other constants

Tags: r

I have some logic that test for changes in values.  As a certain threshold is reached a new constant claims the first spot, which is s0, and the rest are "pushed up" meaning the first becomes the second and the second becomes the third...Here is an example:

the initial state of my data might look like this:

```
s3 <- 7
s2 <- 5
s1 <- 4
s0 <- 2
```

Some test is run and s0 is redefined to a lower value like s0 = 1.  at that time my variables need to be shifted up and a new "level" added as follows:

```
s4 <- 7
s3 <- 5
s2 <- 4
s1 <- 2
s0 <- 1
```

I know how to redefine s0 but I am not sure how to adjust the name of the other constants accordingly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not very fast and not the best practice in memory management, but you could simply use `s <- c(1, s)`. So you can update `s[1]` and the index of all other values would be increased by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have all these values in one vector, instead of stored as separate objects.

Initial state:

`state <- c(2, 4, 5, 7)`

Update state if `new_value` is less than all previous values:

`if (new_value < min(state)) state <- sort(c(state, new_value))`

Then you can always reference the current minimum value by `state[1]`.

Comment: Sometimes the solution is much easier than you might think, I think this will solve it for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not very efficient and I don't recommend this method. As commented/answered you should put your variables in the same structure ( list or vector). I show it just because the solution use some useful functions to deal with variable defines in the global environment ( switch from separate variables to a list and vice versa) .

That's said, here I define a function that do the job. It defines a new s0 and shift the name of others variables. Internally the function create a list (by gathering variable using some pattern) , shift its names and return again a separate variable to the global environment.

```
push <- function(value){
  ## call of gloabl variable twice here , once for ls and for mget
  ## not really elegant!
  oo = mget(ls(pattern='s[0-9]+',envir=.GlobalEnv),envir=.GlobalEnv)
  list2env(setNames(c(value,oo),c(names(oo),paste0('s',length(oo)))),
           envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Then you can redefine a new s0 like this :

```
push(1)
```

You test the result :

```
unlist(mget(ls(pattern='s[0-9]+')))
s0 s1 s2 s3 s4 
 1  2  4  5  7
```